# plotWidget doesn't display proper labels

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

In my 'UI-pyqtgraph' application, I can't get my labels displayed properly on plots. I tried several different tricks but I obviously missuse the combination plotWidget/pyqtgaph. Can you tell me what is wrong ?

For example, here is a toy code that shows 2 curves (crosses and dots). Why are my labels 'result number 1' and 'result number 2' not displayed ?

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, uic

uifilename = 'testUI211014.ui'
form_class = uic.loadUiType(uifilename)[0]

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindowClass()

    x = np.arange(10)
    y1 = x**1.5
    y2 = x**2
    win.graphicsView.plot(x,y1, label='result number 1',symbol='x')
    win.graphicsView.plot(x,y2, label='result number 2',symbol='o')
    win.graphicsView.setLabel('bottom', text='x')
    win.graphicsView.setLabel('left', text='y')
    win.show()

    app.exec_()
```

This gives:
[image]
with no label displayed...

I would appreciate regular labels, sampled and commented in a readable and reasonable size text, inside a frame, like usual labels. For instance like the matplotlib version:
[image]

---

I found that if I use 'labelItem' with, for instance, 3 lines inserted just before the 'win.show()':

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
labelValue = pg.LabelItem('result number 1')
win.graphicsView.addItem(labelValue)
```

then 'result number 1' appears, but huge, upside down, unframed and not sampled. Like that:
[image]

---

the file 'testUI211014.ui' is just a plotWidget in a mainWindow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="PlotWidget" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>671</width>
      <height>471</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>42</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QGraphicsView</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

update monday the 18th of october (2021) at 10:30am:

It seems there could be a versioning problem, since my descriptions above were in the framework of a previous project using python 3.5. When I run these toy codes in a python 3.9 environment I get nothing displayed (not even the curves)... what's wrong ?

---

update november 2, 10am

1. I forgot to say the usual `addLegend()` command, like in matplotlib or in the answer below, doesn't work (no display, no message, nothing...)
2. everything's ok when I remove the lines:

   win.graphicsView.plot(x,y1, label='result number 1',symbol='x')
   win.graphicsView.plot(x,y2, label='result number 2',symbol='o')

and add:

```
c1 = win.graphicsView.plot(x,y1,symbol='x')
c2 = win.graphicsView.plot(x,y2,symbol='o')
import pyqtgraph as pg
legend = pg.LegendItem((80, 60), offset=(70, 20))
legend.setParentItem(win.graphicsView.graphicsItem())
legend.addItem(c1, 'result number 1')
legend.addItem(c2, 'result number 2')
```

just before the `show()`. I wonder why `addLegend()` is useless...

But the main problem that was raised is solved, since I can display my labels.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP wants is to show the legend so for this he has to:

- Use the addLegend() method
- Set the text through the name property.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindowClass()

    x = np.arange(10)
    y1 = x ** 1.5
    y2 = x ** 2
    win.graphicsView.addLegend()
    win.graphicsView.plot(x, y1, name="result number 1", symbol="x")
    win.graphicsView.plot(x, y2, name="result number 2", symbol="o")
    win.graphicsView.setLabel("bottom", text="x")
    win.graphicsView.setLabel("left", text="y")
    win.show()

    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: I must play with it: with python 3.5, I still get the plot without any label; with python 3.9 I still get nothing at all...

Comment: @Stéphane What version of PyQt5 and pyqtgraph do you use?